# Setting WinSCP ResumeSupport.State is ignored

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I an trying to perform a synchronization in a C# script in SSIS. I would like to turn off `ResumeSupport.State`. I am using the code below, but I still get an error message of:

> Transfer was successful, but temporary transfer file could not be renamed...

Thank you for any help!

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    // Disable transfer with resume support/to temporary filename for all files
    transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.Off;
    MessageBox.Show(transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State.ToString());

    // Synchronize files
    SynchronizationResult synchronizationResult;
    synchronizationResult =
        session.SynchronizeDirectories(
            SynchronizationMode.Local, sLocalFolder, "/", false);

    // Throw on any error
    synchronizationResult.Check();

    session.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use the `transferOptions` variable.

You have to pass it to [`Session.SynchronizeDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories):

```cs
session.SynchronizeDirectories(
    SynchronizationMode.Local, sLocalFolder, "/", options: transferOptions);
```